# Mapping a high level statement back in assembly dump

Tags: disassembly, decompilation, c, objdump

Say, I have compiled a large code base, e.g. gzip/gmp/python/php etc. on Linux. Is there any means to map a high level C construct, e.g. assignment/if-else/for/while/Math expression back in the assembly dump produced by `objdump` or something similar? Please let me know how far it is possible in both the cases when debug information is present and absent.

Comment: Do you want to decompile the code or map assembly to original source ?

Comment: It sounds like what you're asking is, "is it possible to reverse engineer software?" So if I'm understanding you correctly, the answer is, "yes."

Comment: Note that just about any of your original "ssignment/if-else/for/while/Math expression" in the C source may be optimized beyond recognition, or even entirely be omitted. I.e., even with the lowest compiler optimization settings, you won't find the "5" of a statement `i = 100/5;` back in your executable. (Assuming any 21st century compiler was used.)

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to outline a possible ways you can go:

1. If you compile with debug symbols, you can use *objdump* to produce a more readable disassembly.
2. if you give *gcc* the flag `-fverbose-asm`, the assembler it emits will be a lot clearer to read.
3. Use the `-S` (note: capital **S**) switch to *gcc*, and it will emit the assembly code to a file with a **.s** extension. For example, the following command:
   `gcc -O2 -S -c foo.c` will leave the generated assembly code on the file **foo.s**.

Also, you can generate this in **AT&T** syntax as well as in **Intel** syntax: `gcc -S -masm=att code.c` `gcc -S -masm=intel code.c`

Frankly, I've digested the info from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289881/using-gcc-to-produce-readable-assembly%22%20here%22). Hope it will help.

EDIT: some useful links:

[The info that's more specific to your question](http://www.limitedwish.org/threethings/2012/05/11/c-objdump-asm/)

[Looks very promising except that the project is abandoned](http://www.eresi-project.org/browser/trunk/testsuite/elf/etrel_inject/etrel_original)